# How can I create a launchd agent that will run only once?

Tags: macos, launchd

Since there is no "Year" parameter in the `launchd` plist format, how is it possible to create an agent that will run only once and not once a year?

Comment: "Only once" as in once per cold boot or once in the existence of that system?

Comment: "only once" as in "only once". My understanding is that the fact that Year is not a possible parameter makes any agent minimally a yearly agent since it is not possible to specify a unique date.
I want the agent to work only once, on a unique date.

Comment: Did you ever get answer to this? I am trying to do the same and my unload script is not working reliably.

Comment: Did anyone figure out this? The closest thing I've found is https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2592680?answerId=12334487022#12334487022 but it's not very clear.

Comment: I think it's not possible. Because there is no way to set a single point in time.
I seem to remember that I posted that question around the time I wrote this blog article: https://mac4translators.blogspot.com/2017/12/automation-scheduling-file-and.html

There are plenty of references that I had gathered during the writing process. Maybe you'll find an answer there, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

Since your reference "Year",  I assume you are using StartCalendarInterval.
If you don't want to run at an interval,  use the RunAtLoad key, which will cause it to run once each time the system starts.

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
```

Now if you truly only want the script to run once (ever),  don't use launchctl at all,  just run it once on the command line and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The issue is that I want to set an event to take place only once in the future. So it's not like I want to run it right now or want to wait until that time. I want to set the date and be done with it. I do understand that launchd may not be the best tool for that though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the key `LaunchOnlyOnce` for this:

```
<key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
<true/>
```

This will launch the agent only once **if the system is not rebooted**.

Comment: Which is not what I am asking. See my comment above.
I need either a way to create a unique date, or a way to unload the agent once it has worked once, etc. If launchd syntax does not allow for that I'm fine, I can use an external script to check that, I just need to know if it's possible within the launchd syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, the launchd system is responsible for starting and managing daemons, agents, and other system processes. To create a launchd agent that runs only once, you can use the `StartCalendarInterval` key in the plist file to schedule the job and then remove the plist file or unload the job after it has run.

Here's an example plist file that you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.example.runonce</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/path/to/your/script.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Day</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>Month</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

In this example, the job is scheduled to run on January 1st at midnight. You can adjust the Minute, Hour, Day, and Month values according to your preferences.

After creating the plist file, you can load the job using the following bash  command:

```
launchctl load /path/to/com.example.runonce.plist
```

Once the job has run, you can unload it using:

```
launchctl unload /path/to/com.example.runonce.plist
```

Alternatively, you can delete the plist file after the job has run.

The specific values in the `StartCalendarInterval` key are used to define the date and time when the job should run. Adjust them accordingly to set the desired one-time execution schedule for your task.

Comment: The intent of the question was to automatically create a launch agent for a date in the future and have it run on that date, and that was all. I can't just "erase" the launch agent after it has run, unless I keep track of which launch agents I have created and when to erase them. The point is, it is not possible to create such a launch agent with the current options.